# How to use maven artifact in the development of Eclipse plugin via Tycho

Tags: maven, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, saxon, tycho

Since version 2.2.0 Tycho has introduced [a new feature](https://github.com/eclipse/tycho/blob/master/RELEASE_NOTES.md#support-for-m2e-pde-maven-target-locations) to allow using maven artifacts in PDE target platforms, and here's the [how-to](https://xn--lubisoft-0za.gmbh/en/articles/using-maven-artifacts-in-pde-rcp-and-tycho-builds/). Following its instructions I have included [an artifact of Saxon-HE](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.saxon/Saxon-HE) into my target platform. I can see the wrapped OSGi bundle of Saxon after ticking the Show Location Content option in the Target Definition Editor. Also I ran `mvn clean verify` command to make sure that the artifact is downloaded into my computer. However,

- as I began to try to import the package into my Eclipse plugin code, I found no suggestions from this package.
- When I tried to include the package as a feature in the Product Editor, I couldn't find any option.
- In addition, when attempting to include it as required plugin / imported packages in the Plugin Editor, there was no option, too.
- What's more, the product produced by `mvn clean verify` did not contain such plugin as Saxon-HE after checking my whole RCP project.

All the efforts in vain above made me wonder how I can use a maven artifact in my plugin development. I desperately need the functionalities Saxon-HE provides with to enhance my plugin. Anyone experienced sharing your expertise?

-- 2021.08.13 update --
Manually I included this plugin in the plugin list of my RCP project via source file editing. Its jar file appeared in the plugin folder of the product. But anyway I was not able to validate the availability of the library in the dependency tab of the plugin manifest editor as shown in [Vogella's tutorial](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseJarToPlugin/article.html#validate-availability-of-the-library). Restarting the IDE did not help, either. This might mean that I have to manually code the source code without the content assistance.